# Access denied for mysql user

Tags: mysql

I get this error when I try to access my database via the user `'spot'@'localhost'` identified by its password.

```
PermissionsError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'spot'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", None)
```

I create this user using these two lines:

```
create user 'spot'@'localhost' identified by 'fakepasswd';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'spot'@'localhost';
```

When I run this code locally, it works fine. When I run this code on a different machine, I get the aforementioned error. 
Yet when I run `show grants for 'spot'@'localhost'` on both machines, they both give me the same output:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'spot'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*196BDEDE2AE4FRO4CA44C47D54D78478C7E2BD7B7'
```

How can I debug this access problem?

Comment: Check the password used.

Comment: If you're running it remotely, why does it say `@localhost`? It should say the name or IP of the client host that's connecting to the remote DB server.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'm just running it on another machine, from the other machine (locally).

Comment: There could be an anonymous user `''@localhost` that you need to drop ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11216911/1446005) for explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to grant privileges not only from localhost, run this querys:

```
create user 'spot'@'%' identified by 'fakepasswd';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'spot'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

This allow the user to connect from ANY ip, you can replace the `%` with the ip of your server.