# Access Denied mysql after creating user, granting, and flushing

Tags: mysql

I am making this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756674/1197775.

But I am getting this:

```
mysql -uspot -pfakepasswd
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'spot'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How can I debug this problem?

## Update

I also tried [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw).

No anonymous users anymore, but no luck yet.

## Update 2

SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;

```
+------------------+-------------------+
| User             | Host              |
+------------------+-------------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1         |
| root             | ::1               |
| spot             | %                 |
| root             | localhost         |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: What are the results of SELECT * FROM mysql.user;  ?

Comment: By the way, please redact your password hashes.

Comment: redact? what does it mean?

Comment: That means don't paste your password hashes in when you answer my question. :)

Comment: I see your answer up there.  What's showing up in the log when you get that error?

Comment: should I use host option or connect through socket? I understand from that table connection from any host is allowed for `spot` ...

Comment: How did you drop the anonymous user? You may need to flush privileges (or just restart your server). Also yes try to specify the `-h` option, just in case. Are you connecting from localhost?

Comment: Is password blank for spot in mysql.user table?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'mysql -u spot -p' and then enter the password.